# How to detect an whether a Wi-Fi adapter has compatibility with Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, hardware, compatibility

Which properties of a Wi-Fi adapter could indicate whether it is compatible with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

The chipset.

Most of the chipsets are made by the same few companies and the Wi-Fi adapter is just rebranded to the company's name that sells the adapter. So basically when 1 chipset gets support or dropped a whole set of adapters become supported or become useless.

- [kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers) has a list of supported chipsets.
- [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) is always a good choice.

Pick a device driver/chipset from the 1st link and then google it to find brands that use that driver/chipset.